# Symfony2 Change Message "Bad credentials." on login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use Symfony2. When an user login on my app if there is an error the default message "Bad credentials." appear. I woud like to change the message. (I am not using FOSUser)

Answer (score 2):

I'm following this page in symfony's doc:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

Its works to me.

```
{% if error %}
   <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}   </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Note that translations have to be [enabled](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration) so Symfony can use his integrated translation messages

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a translation with the following key, or override the login view to make your own one, with your keys.

To solely override the message, create a translation key in `app/Resources/translations/security.en.yml` (example):

```
Invalid credentials.: Invalid credentials.
```

This key is defined in the [security domain](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d94d837e9ea75d76eeb0a43e0535a5e7a7a01542/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Resources/translations/security.en.xlf#L18-L19).

Comment: This is not working for me. The error message is on this page : https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L73

Comment: Siol, it should be working as the exception is translated. See https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/749fc98b24ae7b5f1218aa266649aaefc7746bcd/Exception/BadCredentialsException.php. The translation key is `Invalid credentials.`. Did you clear your cache after adding the file I suggested?

Comment: I cleared the cache but nothing happen, I still see the "Bad credentials" error message.

Comment: Sorry my fault, the error message on the view was not translated. I change {{ error.message }} with {{ error.message|trans }} and it's now working well

Comment: When you say you changed `{{ error.message }} to {{ error.message|trans }}` what file are you changing?

Comment: He probably means the twig template file where the message is to be shown. If you are using the FOSUserBundle and override its templates, this error appears in the "symfony/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig" file as "error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security')".